# Wordpress suddenly not recognising CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I originally referenced the CSS in the `<head>` section of `header.php`:

```
<link href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After it stopped working, I tried enqueuing it in `functions.php`:

```
function add_styles_scripts()
{
    wp_register_style( 'style',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
}
```

(Above I've left out the rest of the CSS/JS files that were already enqueued, for simplicity.)

Wordpress does see the CSS file as it recognises the notes in the head as my custom theme:

```
/*
Theme Name: onesquad
Author: Erin Culleton
Description: One Squad
Version: 0.0.1
Tags: One Squad
*/
```

but it only displays the raw html, and Chrome devtools doesn't find any trace of it either.

It's located in the root folder of my theme.

Could it be a database problem? I have no idea where to even start looking.

Many thanks.

******EDIT******

`index.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

    endwhile; endif; 

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function in a hook. Please find the code below :

```
function add_styles_scripts()
{
    wp_register_style( 'style',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles_scripts', 100 );
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a child theme, add Template to the styles, it must be the parent of your current theme.
Like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: onesquad
Author: Erin Culleton
Description: One Squad
Version: 0.0.1
Tags: One Squad
Template: parenttheme
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do this from now on. It hasn't changed the situation though unfortunately :(

Comment: how does your header.php and index.php look like?

Comment: When this problem started, I had a `content.php` and a very short `index.php` - I reverted to putting the actual content in the `index.php` and getting rid of the `content.php` file to see if that would help. It didn't. But now that I have switched them back, so that I could show you a shortened version of my `index.php` and not my entire site's contents, everything seems to be working again (though I still don't know why it stopped working...). My apologies for the trouble, but thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: However... Now it only shows the header and footer, and nothing from `content.php`. I'm assuming there's something wrong with the code in the middle of my `index.php`. Any idea what it could be? (contents of `index.php` in original post, after ***edit***)

Comment: Also, if I try to change the name of `content.php` to `front-page.php` (as it is a static front page, so actually no Loop necessary), then all the CSS disappears - I believe this is where my troubles started :/ I think I will start a new topic with this info as the problem has shifted. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the head notes and header/footer hooks in the front-page.php, causing it not to load properly, I assume. All CSS and content now back.